# Extend Ext.data.Model (add fields dynamically)

Tags: javascript, model, extjs4

I extended an existing Model by adding fields using the prototype. Everything works fine, the data can be received from the server side and can be used on client side. But, when I now update my data and send it back to the server side, the "new" fields are not recognized by the writer of the proxy.

To be more specific: I have a model like this:

```
    Ext.define('Osgaar', {
      extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
      fields: [
        { name: 'first', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'second', type: 'string' },
        { name' 'third', type: 'string' }
      ],

      proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'public/svcmethod',
        reader: {
          type: 'json',
          root: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
          type: 'json',
          writeAllFields: false
        }
      }
    });
```

I am extending the model like that:

```
    Osgaar.prototype.fields.add({ name: 'fourth', type: 'string' });
```

I tried to set `writeAllFields` to `false` to get *all* attributes transferred, there are just those from the defined model, not the one added using the prototype (Fiddler confirms that).

Does anybody now a way to solve this without defining a new model?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the best solution here is the following:

```
Osgaar.prototype.fields.add(new Ext.data.Field({ name: 'fifth', type: 'string'})); // create Ext.data.Field constructor, not just simple Object
```

I did a quick look on the [Writer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Writer.html#Ext-data-writer-Writer-method-write) implementation, and here is a method that is called by **write()** when you write data:

```
getRecordData: function(record) {
        var isPhantom = record.phantom === true,
            writeAll = this.writeAllFields || isPhantom,
            nameProperty = this.nameProperty,
            fields = record.fields,            // <- look here
            data = {},
            changes,
            name,
            field,
            key;

        if (writeAll) {
            fields.each(function(field){
                if (field.persist) {           // <- checks the persist property!
                    name = field[nameProperty] || field.name;
                    data[name] = record.get(field.name);
                }
            });
```

Then I checked the value of **persist** property of a field that's added to the prototype after the model is defined and turned out it's *undefined*. This is because you are not truly creating an *Ext.data.Field* instance that would inherit all Field defaults and other useful stuff, you're simply adding a plain Object to the fields collection. Osgaar.prototype.fields is just a *MixedCollection* and since you're working with it directly, there's no place where *Ext.data.Field* constructor might be called implicitly.

If it's common for your application logic to add Model fields on the fly, consider implementing an **addField()** method to your custom Models (create another base class in the inheritance chain).

Hope this helps, good luck!
I've been using ExtJS for quite a while so this was like a quiz to me :)

Comment: That's the solution. Adding fields in the definition itself seems to set `persist` to `true` (this might be done by the `ModelManager`, but haven't had a look on that). When adding this via prototyp it has to be set manually. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated my answer, see a slightly better solution and a bit more research

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanations. This makes sense to me. I'll give it try :)

Comment: By the way you don't need to add 'persist: true' in new Ext.data.Field() constructor since it's already true by default.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution for my original issue.

Instead of adding the fields to the prototype of the model I did the following:

```
Osgaar_Temp = Osgaar;
delete Osgaar;

Ext.define('Osgaar', {
    extend: 'Osgaar_Temp',
    fields: 
    [
        { name: 'typeCategories', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

This seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Every time you do this you add another node to the inheritance chain which potentially leads to performance decrease in the best scenario. I wouldn't call this solution reliable, besides it's many more lines of code than directly adding a field to fields collection.

Comment: It's just called once, so I can't see an issue here. Yes, there might be more lines of code, but it seems to be the more beautiful solution, as you can use default behavior without doing something special, IMO.

Comment: I wouldn't call this solution *beautiful*, you're basically hacking the class inheritance framework to achieve desired results. In the end you get a class that inherits from itself...